# App crashes when I try and release an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've kept the code as simple as I can. And included only what is really necessary for the app to function as it needs to.

But I'm still getting a crash that i cannot explain. There is no error message. It appeared when I added the line [parser release];

parser which is a XMLParser object crashes when I release, happens even if its a locally alloced and released or if i make it a member variable and release in the dealloc method.

Here is the code of the little class its used in.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class WebServiceAPI, RadioAppDelegate, XMLParser;
@interface WebServiceAPI : NSObject
{   
    XMLParser *parser;
    FootballRadioAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
@end


#import "WebServiceAPI.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation WebServiceAPI

-(void) getRadioStationList//:(id) aDelegate;
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://bdoyle.kingpinhosting.com/Radios.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [url release];
    parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [xmlParser release];
    xmlParser = nil;    
}
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
}   

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didFailWithError:(NSError*) error
{
}   

-(void) dealloc
{
    [parser release];
    parser = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

If I leave the code without a call to release of 'parser' then it works perfect. But obviously it's a memory leak.

Comment: Don't name methods 'get*' unless you are getting in the Cocoa/iOS sense of getting, which you aren't doing here.  Convention would be simply `radioStationList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check whether have a allocate memory on an object by using

> NSLog(@"parser allocation %d",[parser retainCount])

and try to empty the delegate

> [parser setDelegate:nil]

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing parser on the "getRadioStationList" method and not assigning it to nil. Then on the dealloc of the class you are releasing it again.

You should avoid releasing twice or assign to nil after releasing.

Comment: was a typo. Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're releasing parser twice; once in dealloc and once in getRadioStationList.

Comment: Thats a typo! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If `parser` is an instance variable, the commented out `release` in `radioStationList` would be wrong.  That would not be a leak assuming you want the parser to survive until `dealloc`.

If XMLParser is following the standard `delegate` pattern, then it won't retain `parser` and, thus, that `release` would likely lead to an over-release or crash later.

There should be a backtrace if you are crashing.  Or a crash log.  Post it, please.   Also, try running with Zombies enabled and see if you get more information.

Comment: OK. Thanks for those points. Can we please ignore the typo from now on.